# Removing some characters from a string

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have some strings like this in Python:
' سلام دوستان;\xa0\xa0ج\xa0۲ \xa0ص\xa0۳۸۸ مى شود راهی پیدا کرد\u200c'
How I can remove all \xa0 and \u200* characters from the strings?

Comment: `replace` method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `replace` method , to replace those characters with empty string.

```
original_string =  'سلام دوستان;\xa0\xa0ج\xa0۲ \xa0ص\xa0۳۸۸ مى شود راهی پیدا کرد\u200c'

new_string = original_string.replace('\xa0','').replace('\u200','')
```